# how to check the username exist in database or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication

This is my code
I don't know what's my fault but it is not checking whether the username exist in database or not.

```
    String connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost; Database=pramod; User ID=itesuser; password=ites; Port=3309;";
                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                con.Open();
                String query = "select * from logins where USERNAME=@username and PASSWORD=@password";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
    
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
    
                MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
              
                int i = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                
    
         
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    Response.Write("username wrong");
                }
    
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Session["username"] = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
                    Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
                }
                else {
                    Label1.Visible = true;
                    Label1.Text = "Your password is incorrect";
                    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    
                }
                con.Close();
```

it is checking whether the password is correct or wrong but not the username, now i need to check username and the the password

Comment: Are you storing passwords in plain text? Don't do that, it's horrible security! Also, don't tell users if the username is wrong, just tell them the login failed. Any time you give users more detail than necessary gives them more chance to break into your code.

Comment: it's my task i have to show username is wrong @DavidG

Comment: Then you should tell your boss what a bad idea that is. I'm not going to help someone make an app less secure I'm afraid. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think your clue is here:

> `String query = "select * from logins where USERNAME=@username and PASSWORD=@password";`

By doing this, you check the username and password at the same time. So if the username OR the password is incorrect, you get 0 rows in your result.

To get what your want, only mention the username in the SQL query, and if you get a record, you compare the password in .Net code.
So:

```
String query = "select * from logins where USERNAME=@username";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text.Trim());

MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
```

And then check the password if you get 1 row back.

This looks like an insecure way of handling logins, so I hope you at least will hash and salt the passwords. Now you are one database leak away from a very embarasing situation. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=password+hashing+and+salting